# Running Google-Chrome and VS Code as non-root user?

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, root, users

First, When I run *google chrome* as **regular user** (non-root user), and reboot my lab the changes will be removed as I've already installed, I knew that I should not run it as **root user**, so how can I run it as **non-root** user **and** save changes at the same time ?!

Second, When I run *vs_code* as **root user** a message pop-up says "it's not recommended to run VS Code as root user". I googled this billions of times and no answer how to run it as **non-root** user and when I made a new user account and run it after closing it I face the same probleme with *google-chrome*. I'm done of trying this with no result.. anyone **CAN HELP ME, PLEASE** ???

**NOTE:** I tried also to run vs code from new user while I'm logging in root user and I got this message **"mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/1000’: Permission denied"**, could it be solved ?

Help PLease...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, which version of Ubuntu you try these and what are the commands?

Comment: Please clearly describe the steps you did to install Ubuntu, and then to install Chrome and VS Code on Ubuntu. A link to any instructions you followed would be very helpful.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka , I tried this on Kali Linux , and I made a new user to open Google Chrome used these commands while I'm logging in root user : 
$ su - hadi                (this is my user name) 
$ google-chrome 
and then google chrome will open. 

and to open vs code I do the same : 
su - hadi 
$ code . 

and I got this err : "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/1000’: Permission denied"

I only can open it as root use like this :
code --user-data-dir="root"
and once it open a message pop-up says: "it's not recommended to run VS Code as root user"

Comment: @user535733
This is a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA5rcQSxSNw&t=227s
I followed his steps to install kali linux.

and here is a link to how I installed google-chrome:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-on-kali-linux/

but any way, I didn't open it with --no-sandbox.

and this is link how I installed vs code using snap command:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka
I can also open chrome like this :
su hadi -c  google-chrome

Comment: This is an Ubuntu forum, even though it is difficult to understand that the instructions you brought here. It doesn't make a sense why you have to be a root user and operating them as a normal user like that, using common sense, you should logout 'root' and login as 'hadi' and open google-chrome and vscode.